# Implement Write-Behind Cache using Hazelcast

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I am doing a PoC on **"write-behind cache"** using Hazelcast.

Let's say I have two services/microservices:

1. "**HZServer**" (running on ports 9091, 9092, 9093). I have included the below dependencies in this service:

- *'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all: 4.0.3'*
- *'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'* 
  I have implemented MapStore in this service and connected to **PostgreSQL** using CRUDRepository. only HZServer will be communicating with the database.
  I have configured this as a Hazelcast server. Also, if my understanding is correct, Hazelcast is running as an embedded server here.
  Defined a MapConfig named "Country" with its MapStoreConfig implementation 'CountryMapStore'.

2. "**MyClient**" (running on ports 8081, 8082, 8083.... ). I have included the below dependencies in this service:

- *'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all: 4.0.3'*  (I could have used just hazelcast-client).
  I have configured it as a Hazelcast client using "Hazelcast-client.yaml". I also have some RestControllers defined in MyClient service. So, MyClient service will be communicating with the HZServer (Cache) only, and not the DB. I am fetching the "Country" map from the HZInstance in the below manner:
  `IMap<String, Country> iMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("Country");` 
  Fetching and Putting the key value pairs in the below manner: 
  `Country country = iMap.get(code);      // Fetching` 
  `iMap.put(code, country);               // Inserting or Updating`

Please suggest me if this is the only way of achieving "Write-Behind" cache in Hazelcast?
Please find the architecture diagram below:

[image: HZ PoC Architecture]

Answer (score 0):

Very detailed context, this is great!

True "Write-behind" means the interactions between Hazelcast server and the database are asynchronous. Thus, it depends on the exact configuration of the `MapStore`.

Note that in that case, you may lose data. Again, this depends on your specific implementation (*e.g.* you may retry until the transaction has been acknowledged).

Comment: Q1. Is this the only way to implement "Write-Behind" with Hazelcast? or is there any better approach? 
Q2. If my understanding is correct, Hazelcast is running as an embedded server in "HZServer" service, right?